# How to find the number of times a specific day of the week occurs during a given time period

Tags: php

I am trying to handle groups which meet either once a week, twice a month or once a month - on any day of the week.  I would like to calculate the number of occurrences any given configuration would generate for a given time frame.

For example, say a group meets every Friday, from Jan 1 to June 30, how many times would they meet?  Or, if a group meets on Tuesday every other week, from Jan 1 to June 30, how many times would they meet?  Etc.

Is this possible in php?  I'm not seeing a solution in the [DateInterval manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php).

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all, you know that if there are N days between two dates, there are at least floor(N/7) of each day of the week.  But it may be one more than that.

From Jan 1 to June 30 of this year (2012), for instance, is 182 days (assuming both endpoints are included).  That's exactly 26 weeks, so there are exactly 26 of each day of the week. 
From Jan 1 to June 30 of next year, however, is only 181 days, or 25 weeks plus 6 days. It also happens to be 26 Fridays, but only 25 Mondays.

I recommend @philmccull's answer from the 'possible duplicate' link above.

Comment: Thanks for the great link, Mark.  I guess I did not find it due to the title - so for that reason I won't vote for the post to be close.  Once I know the number of times a specific day occurs within the time frame then I can divide by the interval (biweekly, once a month).  Nice link addressing the heart of the matter.  Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

So, I think the gist of it is to

1) figure out how many 'periods' there are in the span (so, if the span is 35 days, and meetings are every other week, you have two full sets (28 days))

2) investigate the remaining days outside of a full cycle (essentially the modulus)

and then the total is: (number of periods)*(meeting days per period)+(how many days of the remainder are meeting days)

I'm not saying this is the most efficient code (nor does it have input validation), but here is a way to achieve it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST["start"])){
    $cycle=$_REQUEST["recur"]*604800;//number of weeks to seconds
    $start=strtotime($_REQUEST["start"]);
    $end=strtotime($_REQUEST["end"])+(24*60*60);//end has been extended to be inclusive
    $duration=$end-$start;
    $periods=floor($duration/$cycle);
    $remainder_start=$start+($periods*$cycle);
    $number_of_days=($end-$remainder_start);
    while($number_of_days>604800){//this piece reduces the set to test to just the final week of the remainder (if a meeting is every three weeks, you don't need to test the first 14 days of the remainder)
        $number_of_days=$number_of_days-604800;
        $remainder_start=$remainder_start+604800;
        }
    $number_of_days=$number_of_days/(24*60*60);
    $d=getdate($remainder_start+1);
    $rem_start_day=$d["wday"];//0=sunday

    $days=0;
    if($_REQUEST["sunday"]=='true'){$sunday=true;$days++;}
    if($_REQUEST["monday"]=='true'){$monday=true;$days++;}
    if($_REQUEST["tuesday"]=='true'){$tuesday=true;$days++;}
    if($_REQUEST["wednesday"]=='true'){$wednesday=true;$days++;}
    if($_REQUEST["thursday"]=='true'){$thursday=true;$days++;}
    if($_REQUEST["friday"]=='true'){$friday=true;$days++;}
    if($_REQUEST["saturday"]=='true'){$saturday=true;$days++;}

    $total=$days*$periods;
    $n=$number_of_days;
    for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++){
        switch($rem_start_day){
            case 0:if($sunday){$total++;}break;
            case 1:if($monday){$total++;}break;
            case 2:if($tuesday){$total++;}break;
            case 3:if($wednesday){$total++;}break;
            case 4:if($thursday){$total++;}break;
            case 5:if($friday){$total++;}break;
            case 6:if($saturday){$total++;}break;
        }
        $rem_start_day++;
        $rem_start_day=$rem_start_day%7;
    }
    echo "NUMBER OF INSTANCES:".$total."<br/>";
}
else{
?>
<form action="" method="post">
Start:<input type="text" name="start" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"/><br/>
End:<input type="text" name="end" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"/><br/>
<table>
<tr><td>Sn</td><td>M</td><td>T</td><td>W</td><td>R</td><td>F</td><td>St</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="sunday" value="true"/></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="monday"  value="true"/></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday"  value="true"/></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="wednesday"  value="true"/></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="thursday"  value="true"/></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="friday"  value="true"/></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="saturday"  value="true"/></td></tr></table>
Occurs Every <input type="text" name="recur" style="width:30px"/> Week(s)<br/>
<input type="submit" id="button" value="Go" />
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```